# Exclude Null Entries when concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have columns

```
Col1|Col2|Col3
Aaaa|Bbbb|Cccc
Null|Bbbb|Cccc
Aaaa|Bbbb|Null
```

My result should look like

```
Aaaa,Bbbb,Cccc
Bbbb,Cccc
Aaaa,Bbbb
```

I tried this with the common '+' way of concatenation like

```
Select Col1 + ', ' + Col2 + ', ' + Col3
```

but with this statement I do get Nulls in the resultset if there is a Null in one of the columns. I could do something like

```
ISNULL(Col1, ' ')
```

but this end up in having ',' signs messing around

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONCAT()` function solves your problem:

```
Select CONCAT(Col1, ', ', Col2, ', ', Col3)
```

It ignores `NULL` values.

The most recent versions of SQL Server support `CONCAT_WS()`:

```
CONCAT_WS(', ', col1, col2, col3)
```

This produces slightly different results.  For instance, if the second two values are `NULL`, the first returns `'A,,'` but the second returns `'A'`.  I'm not sure which you really want.

Comment: CONCAT_WS did the job. Thanks a lot!